# Network issues regarding p4300 SAN - cannot manage p4300 through CMC

Tags: networking, storage-area-network, vmware-vsphere, lefthand

I am having an issue with my p4300 LeftHand SAN. It is a 2 node iSCSI system. Each one has 2 nics which are teamed into a cisco switch. The VMware cluster is connected into this switch as well with teamed nics.

My VMware cluster is behaving normally.

My problem is that I need to resize a LUN due to some exchange issues. My problem is that I had to reinstall CMC and it cannot find the SAN servers.

I have tried pining the SAN nodes via multiple different workstations plugged into the switch as well as the switch itself with no success. I have gotten onto the VMware hosts' console and did some management NIC ping test and that seems to succeed in pinging the SAN hosts.

So, any clues on where to start?

Thanks,

Comment: Are the ports on the switch that the SAN is connected to in a different VLAN?

Comment: wow - didnt even think about checking that... I could ping almost all other devices on that switch so I didn't that that was an issue... Sure enough, they were on different vlans.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the SAN from the VMware hosts but not other hosts, then it's a network issue, not a SAN issue. Check the VLAN settings of the switch ports for your SAN.